# Defining Callbacks for custom Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, function, architecture, callback

The scenario is i am writing some custom javascript method lets say suppose.

```
function callMe(){
  //Do some stuff and return.
}
```

Now i want to add some functions, i am not sure if they will be treated as  callback but which will be triggered at some point as the ***callMe()*** is being executed. Lets say i want the ***beforecallMe()*** needs to be executed as soon as somebody calls ***callMe()*** methof

```
function beforecallMe(){
// Do something and continue with callMe method
```

}

Again i want to call a method as soon as the callMe has executed its part of code, lets say method ***afterCallMe()*** .

```
function afterCallMe(){
 //Triggered after callMe has executed
}
```

So is there any possible way i can do this in Callbacks or any other way.

Also i want to know if its possible call other custom functions as callbacks when a particular function is going to execute or has executed, somewhat a trigger.

For e.g : There is a method ***sendmail()*** after which i wish to call sometimes ***sendReport()*** or ***startaProgram()*** or ***doSomething()*** and so on. Is there any way to do achieve this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to call functions before and/or after you call another function? You could use custom events, although this can get messy and difficult to maintain. You could write function wrappers that either simply call the functions you want, or accept a function to call (callbacks). There are *many* ways this could be implemented.

Comment: you can hard-code the next function name into the bottom of each function's code. you could use promises, though i don't think that allows a before(). you could also add a callback param to each function, as pass the next function in at call-time to avoid hard-coding function names inside of functions.

Comment: @DaveNewton : I want to trigger things before and after a function is called from anywhere.

Comment: you can write custom Function.prototype methods to define `fn.before(cb)` and `fn.after(cb)`, which could execute the passed function before or after the _this_ function. that would let you code ex: `callMe.after(beforeCallMe).before(afterCallMe)`, would work on almost any functions without modification, and allows calling from anywhere.

Comment: @dandavis : Yeah i can call some functions, but the thing is the trigger function may vary as the function is called from different places and requires to perform different after behavior.

Comment: right, but you can use `callMe2.after(beforeCallMe3).before(afterCallMe4)` from anywhere, which is about the least repetition you can have at call-time that works from anywhere in the program...

Comment: @dandavis : Great, i actually wanted to achieve something like this only.

Comment: ex: http://jsfiddle.net/3h3f2y93/1/

Comment: @dandavis : Perfect, thanks for the fiddle. This should be the answer actually. My bad, I even can't vote your comment up as my rep is really less :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer in the comments as mentioned by Dan Davis in comments.

And the fiddle for the same is

http://jsfiddle.net/3h3f2y93/1/

and Code is :

```
Function.prototype.after=function(fn){
    var f=this;
    return function(){
        return fn.apply(this, arguments), f.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};

Function.prototype.before=function(fn){
    var f=this;
    return function(){
        return f.apply(this, arguments), fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};


function say1(){ alert(1); }
function say2(){ alert(2); }
function say3(){ alert(3); }

//say 2 before you say 1 and after you say 3:
 say2.before(say1).after(say3)();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways to handle this.

Here's two.

One using a function parameter and an object with functions inside it then using callbacks. They're both valid, but callbacks are a bit simpler, if you ask me.

```
//you can pass a parameter and
//use that in a switch statement
//to decide what to do
var funcs = {
    start: function(next) {

        switch (next) {
            case 1:
                this.startProgram();
                break;

            case 2:
                this.sendReport();
                break;

            case 3:
                this.doOtherThing();
                break;

            default:
                console.log('do nada');
                break;
        }
    },

    startProgram: function() {
        console.log("starting a program");
    },

    sendReport: function() {
        console.log("sending report");
    },

    doOtherThing: function() {
        console.log("Doing something else");
    }
};

funcs.start(1)
funcs.start()

//Or you can do it with callbacks
function doSomethingElse(callback) {
    console.log("doing something");
    callback();
}

doSomethingElse(function() {
    console.log("I'm a callback!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this

```
function callMe()
{
    beforeCallMe();
    // CallMe code here
    afterCallMe();
}
```

`beforeCallMe()` will a execute before the rest of the `callMe()` method and then `afterCallMe()` will be executed;

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function as follows:

```
function callMe(beforeCall, afterCall){
  if(typeof(beforeCall) === "function") beforeCall();

  // Your call me code goes here...

  if(typeof(afterCall) === "function") afterCall();
}
```

Usage:

```
callMe(); // No callbacks
callMe(null, afterCall); // Will only call the afterCall
callMe(beforeCall, afterCall); // Will call both the beforeCall and afterCall

function beforeCall() {
  // before call function
}
function afterCall() {
  // after call function
}
```

or you can define as anonymous functions:

```
callMe(function () {
  // before call function
}, function () {
  // after call function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a hundred ways to do something like this. Here is a function that will accept either 3 functions, or an object with the functions defined as parameters.

```
<script>
    function write(txt) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
    }

    function append(txt) {
        var inner = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = inner + "<br>" + txt;
    }

    function callMe(callFunctionOrObject, callBefore, callAfter) {
        if (!callFunctionOrObject) return;

        if (typeof callFunctionOrObject === "object") {
            if (typeof callFunctionOrObject.callBefore === "function") {
                callFunctionOrObject.callBefore();
            }
            if (typeof callFunctionOrObject.call === "function") {
                callFunctionOrObject.call();
            }
            if (typeof callFunctionOrObject.callAfter === "function") {
                callFunctionOrObject.callAfter();
            }
        }
        else if (typeof callFunctionOrObject === "function") {
            if (typeof callBefore === "function") {
                callBefore();
            }
            callFunctionOrObject();
            if (typeof callAfter === "function") {
                callAfter();
            }
        }
    }

    //EXAMPLE USAGE
    append("First Test");
    callMe({
        "callBefore": function() { append("Before call 1"); },
        "call": function() { append("call 1"); },
        "callAfter": function() { append("After call 1"); }
    });

    append("Second Test");
    callMe(
        function() { append("call 2"); },
        function() { append("Before call 2"); },
        function() { append("After call 2"); }
    );
</script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sop22f6z/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically, setup a before and/or after handler, as well as setup context arguments for each function.

The code below has 2 important functions `setupFunctionTriggers` & `removeFunctionTriggers`. The rest of the code and html are just there to show how to use these functions.

A few key techniques used:

1. A Named function can be treated like a variable. It's "value" can be copied read and assigned to (copied and replaced).
2. Use `new Function()` to execute dynamic code.
3. `new Function('return '+funcName+';')();` Will return the named function itself.
4. `new Function('func', funcName+'=func;')(wrapperFunc);` Will replace the function with a new function.

```js
function setupFunctionTriggers(funcName, before, after, beforeArgs, afterArgs) {
  var func = new Function('return '+funcName+';')();
  var wrapperFunc = function() {
    if(before instanceof Function)
      before.apply(this, beforeArgs);
    
    var ret = func.apply(this, arguments);

    if(after instanceof Function)
      after.apply(this, afterArgs);

    return ret;
  };

  new Function('func', funcName+'=func;')(wrapperFunc);
  return func;
}

function removeFunctionTriggers(funcName, original) {
  new Function('func', funcName+'=func;')(original);
}



var log = '';

function callMe(val) {
  log += 'Inside callMe(' + val + ')\n';
  return 'Called me!';
}

function before(val) {
  log += 'Before callMe, with val=' + val + '\n';
}

function after() {
  log += 'After callMe\n';
}


log += 'Call normal function\n';
callMe(12);

log += '\nSetup triggers...\n';
var originalCallMe = setupFunctionTriggers('callMe', before , after, ['B4!']);

var ret = callMe(34);
log += 'callMe returned: ' + ret;

log += '\n\nCall original function (triggers still attached)\n';
originalCallMe(56);

log += '\nReverting...\n';
removeFunctionTriggers('callMe', originalCallMe);

callMe(78);

document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = '<pre>'+log+'</pre>';
```

```html
<span id="log"></span>
```